# Angular js directive not working on dom created by other js library like gridder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

```
<li class="col-sm-4" ng-click="updateCart()" gridder-list" data-griddercontent="#gridder-content-1">


</li>
```

This is the normal html which is not init by js so the angular here works fine

```
<div id="gridder-content-1" ng-click="updateCart()" class="gridder-content">

</div>
```

Now this is the init done by gridder js lib so when I put ng click here the code doesn't work neither does it throw errors.

Comment: You forgot a double quote => <li class="col-sm-4" ng-click="updateCart()"

Comment: What's the purpose of "gridder-list" and "#gridder-content-1" ?
There is a problem in your html.

Comment: http://www.oriongunning.com/demo/gridder/ check out this what it does

Comment: you need '$compile' the html before appending them. check [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: $compile doesn't seem to work. OP, did you get ng-click working with gridder templates?

Comment: @typhoid.99 Have you found any solution for this?